# Generating a receipt/invoice from a billing system

Tags: php, mysql

im working on a hospital billing system. it has a checklist of procedures. i want to generate a receipt so it can be printed and the data should be only from one transaction. i already have the html file for the format of my receipt. 
problem is, getting the info that is needed from the transaction. like the procedures checked, price, patient number, etc.

screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXf0v.png

[image]

if you look at the screenshot, there are steps and different pages until the printing of receipt. so its hard for me to pass the values from the first page, to the last. 
on the second image, i circled the procedure numbers. its just to test that the selected procedures where passed.

in the third image, i cant pass the 2 procedures. which i need to generate the receipt. 
the code is:

```
foreach ($procedure as $pro) {
echo $pro."<br>";
}
```

I cant just add that to the last page since its undefined.

also, i need to get the amount paid and the total for the receipt. I can't picture how i will execute the code cause its too much.

Comment: you will need to post some code - otherwise this is a huge 'do it for me from scratch' type question...

Comment: given the "pass the procedures" and "last page" - sounds like you're using multiple intermediate webpages? as with anything in PHP dealing with multiple pages and passing data between them - use sessions. any page that generates a cost puts that in the session, and then it's available to all pages using sessions.

Comment: What EMR system does your employer use? You should be able to put the charges into the database on selection, then read then back out when its time to print their receipt. I work with a doctors office management company and that is how we handle receipts.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 thats what i thought too. just retrieve the values from a table on a database so you could directly just print it. the problem is, the billing table only has the patient no, bill, and the amount paid. there is no procedure that was checked and the price.

Comment: @user1967153 Somewhere the system has to store what procedures were completed. I have to link ORDERS to LABS to PATIENTS to PAYMENTS to do my receipts.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 I have a separate table where it stores ALL the procedures that were checked. but it shows all of it and i want to print the receipt for only the CURRENT transaaction. So im not sure that theres a possible mysql query command to only output bill for the current transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest taking the POST data from each page and putting them in a SESSION variable, then on the final (print) page just use the session data.

Comment: Like the @Jeremy1026 suggest more as I do not like puttin everything into sessions...

Comment: Either do as suggested above, or put the data into hidden form fields and use that to pass the data along.

Comment: Session works fine. I passed the value. The problem is, it only gets ONE procedure number.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then you do not have your form values setup properly. Without seeing the HTML for the form we can't help with that. Instead of giving your procedure number field the name "procedure_number", call it "procedure_numbers[]" so that it will put each procedure number into an array $_POST['procedure_numbers']. Do a foreach on that array and you will get each procedure number.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate method to using the SESSION is to create a multi-page form with hidden "page values", pass the values from each subsequent `POST` using `hidden` form fields.

The code would look something like...

```
if ($_POST['pg'] == 0) {

    // output first page/form

    echo '<input type="text" name="someValue"/>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="pg" value="1"/>';

}

if ($_POST['pg'] == 1) {

    // output second page/form

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="someValue" value="$_POST['someValue']"/>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="pg" value="2"/>';

}

// etc.
```

Comment: session works fine now but the problem is it only gets ONE checked value. foreach ($procedure as $pro) {
$_SESSION['receipt'] = $pro;
}

Comment: You need to create an array in the SESSION to store multiple values. `$_SESSION['myArray'] = array($key1 => $val1, $key2 => val2)` etc.